# Using multiple queries together in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hey guys i have a query in mongodb where i have to use many queries togther so here is my document in db

```
id:                 ObjectId("5e8c1933ed43d408774f7fb9")
storyTitle:         "no"
storyDescription:   "no"
categoryID:         "5e882ed701e2ba37407328f1"
userID:             "5e896bc2feeed13a5336c066"
dateAdded:          2020-04-07T06:09:55.662+00:00
thankedBy:          ["ratnabh2615@gmail.com"]
thanked:            1
reportedBy:         ["ratnabh2615@gmail.com"]
reported:           1
```

// this is just one example, there are lot of documents like this in my collection

I am receiving my userID and categoryID in post api from client side now what i want is i want to find the documents where

1. categoryID of the document is equal to 'categoryID' which i received from client side
2. userID of the document is not equal to the 'userID' which also i received from client side
3. Then at last sort this collection's documents by order of the size of 'thankedBy' array in descending order

Note - thankedBy Array only get added when user clicks on some button in front end so some documents might not have this field.

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward use of `find` with `sort`, what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you cannot use the `$size` to sort the documents by length of an array in these documents

we can use the `aggregate` pipeline to get the length of each array in each document, then use that length to sort the documents

here is an example

```
// replace MyCollectionName with your one
MyCollectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { // add you search object here
            // you have to convert req.body.categoryID and req.body.userID to type ObjectID instead of Strings so the aggregate pipeline can understand it
            categoryID: req.body.categoryID,
            userID: { $ne: req.body.userID } // any userID except the req.body.userID
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { 
            // do that projection to be able to use the $size operator as it's valid only in $project operation
            // add all the fields you want, if there is some extra field in the documents and you don't need it in the query result, just don't mention it here
            // If you need all the document fields, then you have to list all of them here
            // here I will get these 4 fields only for simplicity (_id, storyTitle, storyDescription, thankedBy)
            _id: 1,
            storyTitle: 1, 
            storyDescription: 1, 
            thankedBy: 1,
            thankedByArrayLength: { $size: "$thankedBy" } // calculating the array length using the $size operator and assign that length to a new property called 'thankedByArrayLength'
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { thankedByArrayLength: -1 } // sort documents by this thankedByArrayLength, 1 for ascending order, -1 for descending order
    }
])
```

now you will get the documents sorted by the length of thankedBy array, either ascending or descending as you define